# How to read from Contacts.app in mutt OS X

Tags: macos, email, contacts, mutt

I'm trying to setup mutt to autocomplete emails from my address book. I've tried using [`contacts`](http://gnufoo.org/contacts/) and the new [`contacts`](https://github.com/tgray/contacts) to no avail. Has anybody successfully done so?

My guess is that this might be related to the *somewhat* recent privacy changes to Contacts.app

*Edit: I'm on Yosemite.*

Comment: For this kind of question, it can be helpful to specify which version of OS X you care about. Especially if the OS X Address Book / Contacts database or API may have changed recently.

Comment: Completely forgot about that. I'm on Yosemite, will update the question accordingly.

Comment: I've run into the same and I'm getting 4/14/15 1:16:51.735 PM contacts[37094]: __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke48: Connection invalid in the system log. I've been trying to find a way to add the contacts binary to the privacy contacts allow section of the preferences. I believe this is where it issue is. but I'm unable to find a method yet.

Comment: Does http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041024163030501 not work?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

https://github.com/tgray/contacts

And this helpful bit for more addressing goodness:

https://github.com/tgray/muttqt

These are both working for me on Yosemite and homebrew mutt.

Comment: Please expand your answer with some explanation, instead of posting just the links.